# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement optapy (from versions: none)

Tags: python, optapy

I am getting this error when I am trying to install optapy:
[image]

Comment: What is your Python version? OptaPy requires Python 3.9 or higher.

Comment: You are right, my python version was 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using Python 3.8 and OptaPy requires Python 3.9 or higher.
I have installed Python 3.10.4 and now I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement optapy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for optapy
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I redo these steps and it fixed the problem:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
```

Comment: python --version , and check whether your system is triggering the right python